# ¿Por qué al querer restar una cantidad de dos tablas relacionadas con un trigger, me resta todas las cantidades?

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

**¿Por qué me resta todos los valores, si solo quiero restar la cantidad que estoy insertando?**

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es, insertar un retiro (TABLA A) de una cierta cantidad, para que en la otra tabla que ya posee un valor mayor (TABLA B) se le pueda restar.
Aparentemente lo conseguí, pero me lo hace con todos los registros que se encuentran en la tabla B.

CREO que me hace falta especificar para que lo haga solamente en la fila de la id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ACTUALIZAR_SALDO AFTER INSERT ON tblretiros
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE tblcuenta SET fltsaldo = fltsaldo - new.fltretiro;


TABLA A
|idretiro | fltretiro | idcliente | vchno_cuenta  
--------  ---------  ---------      --------------
      14       3000          4  785458545856  
      15       5000          4  785458545856   
      48        200          5  214748364734  
      50        200          5  214748364734 




TABLA B
|vchnum_cuenta | fltsaldo | idcliente  
-------------  --------  -----------
215214215218       4000            1
895485458548       7000            3
785458545856      10000            4
214748364734       9000            5
451278693245       9000            8
123234566798       9000            9
784512369878       9000           10
```

Aquí solamente quería restarle 200 al que tiene el id = 5 (de la tabla B)
pero también me lo restó en todos los demás [de la tabla B que tienen los id = (1,3,4,5,8,9,10)].

Comment: Por que tu trigger carece de un *`where`* que ayude a establecer una condición que limite la cantidad de filas que serán modificadas

Comment: Las tablas que participan en el TRIGGER son `tblretiros` y `tblcuenta`, indica en la pregunta cuál es cada tabla en vez de decir que son Tabla A y Tabla B ¿?

Comment: **Adivinando un poco** la consulta debería quedar así: `UPDATE tblcuenta SET fltsaldo = fltsaldo - new.fltretiro WHERE idcliente=NEW.idcliente;` asumiendo que quieres filtrar por  el `idcliente` que acaba de insertarse.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano,  lo había intentado con  Where Vchnum_cuenta  = new.vchno_cuenta, pero no me resultaba.

Comment: @BetaM, si, ya más o menos sabía que me hacía falta ponerle la condición where, solo que me había confundido. 

Comment: ¿Funciona como te he dicho?

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que se pretende es actualizar la fila del que acaba de insertarse, la parte del `UPDATE` debería quedar así:

```
UPDATE tblcuenta 
    SET fltsaldo = fltsaldo - new.fltretiro 
WHERE idcliente=new.idcliente;
```

Esto hará que, cada vez que se inserte una fila en `tblretiros` se actualice `tblcuenta` únicamente en aquella(s) fila(s) cuyo `idcliente` sea igual al `idcliente` de la nueva fila.